# Issue in reading the notification setting in iOS 10

Tags: swift, unusernotificationcenter

In my application I am using the `VoIP push`. When I am trying to read the notification setting; I am getting authorization status `notDetermined`. 
 But user has allowed the push notification. Everything is working fine in iOS 11.

I am using the code below:

```
    if #available(iOS 10,*) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings(completionHandler: { (settings) in
            switch settings.authorizationStatus {
            case .authorized :
                NSLog("Setting Value : AuthoRization Status is : authorized")
            case .denied :
                NSLog("Setting Value : AuthoRization Status is : denied")
            case .notDetermined :
                NSLog("Setting Value : AuthoRization Status is : notDetermined")
            }
```

Comment: did you request authorization using requestAuthorization(options:completionHandler:) in your code ?

Answer (score 0):

**notDetermined** means if your app has never requested authorization using the **requestAuthorization(options:completionHandler:) method.**.

It could be a chance that you will be using a **registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:** instead of **requestAuthorizationWithOptions:completionHandler:**

Deprecated

```
  [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
             UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|
             UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|
             UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
```

New Way :

```
 UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (bool, error) in }
```

Comment: is it solved your issue? If yes please mark it as an answer. It will help others.

Comment: is it solved your issue? If yes please mark it as an answer. It will help others.